# Which GetHashcode will dominate in case of IComparer

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am having the following situation

```
class Custom
{
    public override int GetHashCode(){...calculation1}
}

public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Custom>
{
    public bool Equals(Custom cus1, Custom cus2)
    {
        if (cus1 == null || cus2 == null)
            return false;

        return cus1.GetHashCode() == cus2.GetHashCode();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Custom cus1)
    {
        return ...calculation2;
    }
}

int Main()
{
    List<Custom> mine1 = new List<Custom>(){....};
    List<Custom> mine2 = new List<Custom>(){....};
    MyComparer myComparer = new MyComparer();
    List<Custom> result = mine1.intersect(mine2,myComparer);
}
```

Here Just I want to know which GetHashCode will be used in intersecting.

Comment: `return cus1.GetHashCode() == cus2.GetHashCode();` that is a horrible idea of equality. Seems to me your hash function is not properly designed for speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why didn't you test it yourself? You already have the code...

`MyComparer.GetHashCode` will be used in your case. You can see the code here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#f4105a494115b366

`Custom.GetHashCode` would be used if you didn't specify comparer at `Intersect` call at all.

Comment: So the priority goes first to comparer then to the object. But AFAIK by default objects always get the first priority.

Comment: There is no such a thing as priority here. `Intersect` method uses either comparer provided by user or `DefaultEqualityComparer<T>` when user does not provide a comparer. `DefaultEwualityComparer<T>` calls `GetHashCode` on an object.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, it will be GetHashCode from MyComparer.

**But**, there is a very improtant reason why there is a **GetHashCode** and an **Equals** method. **GetHashCode()** is an optimization, so when the items are initially compared, only the hash code is checked, if the hash code is the same, then the Equals method is used. That avoids the chance of same hashes for different objects (the chance is one in ~4 bilions, but it still happens, seen it first person). In **Equals()** method you should compare all the relevant fields from one object to the other. Comparing objects by hashcode in Equals is wrong and defies the whole purpose of this method.

Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Hash codes as well as getHashCode functions provide a good mechanism for comparing, but you should beware of similarity. In result of limited range supported by hash facilities, it is very common that two different numbers consequence in the same hash-code which may interferes comparison contexts.